# Managing ViewGroup's z-order for LayoutTransition, after removeView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm using a `LayoutTransition` with custom `ObjectAnimator` objects to animate adding and removing Views inside a `LinearLayout` (itself inside a `HorizontalScrollView`). New Views are added to the right of the previous Views. The only property being animated is `translationX`.

I would like a newly-added `View` to slide out from under the `View` directly preceding (animating left to right). And, I would like a newly-removed `View` to slide back under the previous `View` (animating right to left).

I overrode getChildDrawingOrder to return the reverse z-ordering, like so:

```
@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder( int childCount, int i ) {
   return childCount - 1 - i;
}
```

This works great for the animation that occurs when adding Views. It does not work when Views are removed. `removeView()` is called before `getChildDrawingOrder()`; the `ViewGroup` (or, in my case, `LinearLayout`) no longer knows about the newly-removed `View` by the time it gets to figuring out the z order. The result is that the removed `View` animates out on top of the other views.

`bringToFront()` and `bringChildToFront()` seem to do nothing for me.

I know that I can simply translate the `View` I wish to remove, *then* call `removeView()`. But this defeats the purpose of using LayoutTransitions.

What else can I try, to ensure that the removing of a `View` still maintains the z order I want?